# Should I redirect my domains to the same address?

Tags: redirects

If I own example.org, example.com, example.net, and want visiters to view the same site no matter what address they go to, should I redirect two of the addresses to the third, or simply serve up the site without redirection regardless of the addresses used?

Comment: I would be curious to extend this question to include whether it makes any practical difference whether you have http:// redirect to http://www. or other combinations. or should that be its own question?

Comment: @ Damon, I know it makes a difference in google analytics.. I often see two stats for the same page, one with www and one with http://.

Answer (score 5):

Use one domain as a primary domain and redirect the other two to it. Otherwise, besides confusing your users, you will incur duplicate content penalties from Google which obviously are not a good thing.